# Is there a way to add to a combobox list using a textbox and button?

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word, userform

I'm looking for a way to add items to a combobox list without adding the item to the code directly.

[UserForm Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSuzj.png)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ComboBox2
         .AddItem ".020"
         .AddItem ".030"
         .AddItem ".032"
         .AddItem ".040"
   End With

   With ComboBox3
        .AddItem "THK"
        .AddItem "DIA"
        .AddItem "TUBE"
        .AddItem "FORGING"
    End With
End Sub
```

I'd like the user to be able to add an Item into the dropdown list without going into the code. Is there a way to add an .AddItem to the combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike ListBoxes, ComboBoxes allow a user to type a new entry directly into the comboBox field. That's the simplest solution, no extra code required!

If, for some reason, you want to make this more complicated, you can add a text field and a command button. After the user types a new entry in the text field, they click on the button which runs this macro:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  ComboBox3.AddItem TextBox1.value
End Sub
```

Comment: John, Thanks for the help on this one, I'm sure I am doing this the hard way, I am pretty new at this. I'm trying to make it so that the user has to select text from the drop down list and I have turned the entry option off on the comboboxs so it only has the dropdown list. We use an ERP system that is case sensitive and space sensitive, If two people input the same Item into the system but they are not identical it will create a new item instead of finding the existing item in the system. So I'm trying to eliminate double spaces or uppercase/lowercase differences.

Comment: That code you gave me did almost what I need, but it didn't add the Item into the code for future use. Is that possible? I want the user to input it once, then others will select it from the dropdown.

Comment: Your getting into a whole new realm of complexity. The simplest way to do that would be to store the dropdown list in a text file or perhaps in autotext/building block. Your VBA would have to open that text, read it and initialize the dropdown with it. Then when the userform is closed, the list is retrieved and if it's different from the original data, you would write a new list to the text file or building block.

Comment: Re your mention of upper/lower case and spaces, quite a lot has been written about filtering text for duplicates. Using regular expressions can go a long way to eliminating this as an issue. This is _not_ a simple topic, but it's quite powerful: https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-regex-regular-expressions-guide/

Comment: I will start researching how to do it with a text file. Thanks again for you help John!

Comment: Any search terms you could send my way that would help me locate some help on this forum would be great.